# jQGrid - Form Add&Edit editoptions: disabled settings toggling between Add & Edit

Tags: jquery, forms, jqgrid

I am using forms to add and edit records. When adding, I want two columns to be editable. When editing, I don't want the user to edit the values in those columns but I still want to display the data on the form. 
I'm using beforeShowForm to set the disabled for the edit options to disabled:false for add and disabled:true for edit.
The first time I open the add form, everything is ok. When I open it again, the two columns are disabled. If I open the edit form, which has the columns disabled, and go back to add, the columns are again editable.
Please provide information for how I can get the form to be consistently editable. Everything I'm trying so far doesn't work.
Thank you.

```
.jqGrid('navGrid','#pager',{add:true, edit:true, del:true},
            {//add option
                beforeShowForm: function(formid) {
                    $(this).jqGrid('setColProp', 'messageId', {editoptions:{disabled:false}});
                    $(this).jqGrid('setColProp', 'messageSubId', {editoptions:{disabled:false}});
                }
            },
            {//edit option
                beforeShowForm: function(formid) {
                    $(this).jqGrid('setColProp', 'messageId', {editoptions:{disabled:true}});
                    $(this).jqGrid('setColProp', 'messageSubId', {editoptions:{disabled:true}});
                }
            },
            {width: 450}, {width: 450});
```

This is the edit piece of the grid.

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.jgrid.edit, {
ajaxEditOptions: { contentType: "application/json"},
savekey: [true, 13],
closeAfterAdd: true,
recreateForm: true,
closeOnEscape: true,
modal: true,
serializeEditData: function (postData) {
    postData.messageClassId = currentVal;
    return JSON.stringify(postData);
},
afterSubmit: function (response, postdata) {
     $("#msgAdmin").setGridParam({datatype:'json', page:1}).trigger('reloadGrid');
     return [true,'']; // No error
 }, 
beforeSubmit: function(postdata, formid) {
    // Form field validations

afterComplete : function(response, postdata, formid) {                      
    buildGrid();
 },
errorTextFormat: function (response) {
    if (response.status != '200') {
        return 'Error: ' + response.responseText;
    }
    else {
        return 'Data Saved!';
    }
    return [true,'']; // no error
}

});
```